# Select list options with varying font-families - how to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selectlist

It is apparently not possible to give inividual `<option>` tags different `font-family` values.  I would like to achieve this effect somehow.  I've tried the jQuery selectbox plugin, but this doesn't seem to allow me to style the individual options.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% perfect, but this fiddle will get you 90% of the way there:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Y39HQ/

Select a different item from the drop down and then switch back, you'll see the font change for the selected item.

Basically no, you can't do this with the default `<select>`, but the JavaScript, combined with a plugin such as selectBox is not that difficult.

Additionally, styling the individual items in the list you can manage with the css pseudo-selector `nth-child()`.  This will allow you to style each item in the list.  Naturally, if you're manually constructing the items in the drop down, it'd be a lot cleaner to just set the font at the point of creation for the list item....

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this plugin changes the selectbox into a ul li tree, so you can set the font-family on the li's

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

A complete DIY solution perhaps?  When the element is clicked show a  tag with some custom styled  `<li>` items.

Answer (score 0):

The standard HTML `<select><option>...</option></select>` does not allow you to change the font between options. It simply isn't possible.

The jQuery Selectbox plugin which you're using starts off with a standard HTML `<select>` and reskins it.

In theory, because of the reskinning, it would therefore be possible to change the font, but it appears that this plugin limits itself in this area to the standard functionality (perhaps to make it a smoother experience for users that fall-back to the standard HTML); it doesn't appear to support changing fonts.

You might want to consider an alternative plug-in. There are a large number of jQuery plugins to choose from that deal with select box functionality, so you should be able to find one that suits your needs. [This one](http://code.google.com/p/jquerymultipleselectbox/) seems to support modifying the font, for example, but there are plenty of others out there too.

Hope that helps.